# What does the community think about requesting SO and SF to include DevOps to one of the migration options?

Tags: discussion

I created two Q&As to ask [SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392378/2777965) and [SF](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/9586/215599) to include DevOps to the migration options? Does DevOps community agree with this? I think that this could increase the the number of questions that are asked on a daily basis on the SE and second it will improve the focus on SO, SF and DevOps SE.

**December 22, 2019**

[image]

Comment: I think its a good idea :)